# Sumar decimales y enteros

Tags: c#, excel

Para las estadísticas de pitcheo en el béisbol se tiene lo siguiente:

1/3 equivale a 1 out, 2/3 equivalen a 2 outs y 3/3 equivalen a 3 outs.

Cuando se tiene 3 outs se considera 1 inning completo.

Si se tiene 5 outs se considera 1 inning y 2/3 tercios de inning.

En excel en una columna pongo los inning que lanza un pitcher por juego

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la tabla el pitcher Juanito Perez lanzo 4 veces, en la primer vez lanzo 2/3, en la segunda 1/3, en la tercera 5 2/3 y en la ultima 3 1/3, todo esto da que tiene como total 10 innings lanzados.

Lo que necesito es lo siguiente, ahora en lugar de manejar fracciones tengo que usar decimales es decir ahora 1/3 equivale a .1, 2/3 equivale a .2 y 3/3 equivale a 1.

Es decir tomando el ejemplo de la tabla ahora tendría que ponerlo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer esa suma??

Hice este código en C#

```
double[] entradas = { 0.2, 0.1, 5.2, 3.1 };
int enteros = 0;
double tercios = 0.0;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  enteros += (int)Math.Truncate(entradas[j]);

  double num1 = tercios - Math.Truncate(tercios);
  double num2 = entradas[j] - Math.Truncate(entradas[j]);
  double tercio = num1 + num2;

  if (tercio == 0.3)
  {
      if(Math.Truncate(tercios) > 0)
             tercios += (0.3 * 10) / 3;
      else
             tercios = (0.3 * 10) / 3;
   }
   else
      tercios += (entradas[j] - Math.Truncate(entradas[j]));
}

double total = enteros + tercios;

Console.WriteLine(total);
Console.ReadKey();
```

El problema aquí es que cuando suma .2 + .1 me da 0.30000000000000004 y lógicamente no se cumple la condición, por que me esta dando ese resultado cuando debería de dar 0.3?

Comment: mas alla que no entiendo si la pregunta es de programacion o simplemente de excel, no se como sumas 10 de esos numeros.

Comment: matematicamente 2/3 es 0.666666666, no es .2.. y por eso tus matematicas son raras

Comment: @gbianchi es de las dos programación o en excel, la suma da 10 por lo siguiente, .2 + .1 = 1 entonces si sumas 5 + 3 = 8, ahora a esos 8 le sumas el 1 que dio como resultado la suma anterior por lo que ahora tenemos 9, ahora sumas los decimales que tiene el 5 y el 3 y tenemos como resultado 1 y a ese 1 le sumas los 9 que ya tienes y tenemos el 10.

Comment: @gbianchi de acuerdo 2/3 es 0.666666666 pero en estadísticas de béisbol se maneja que 2/3 es .2

Comment: ok. y que intentaste en programacion o excel hasta ahora?

Comment: @gbianchi la verdad no he intentado nada, pero se me ocurre separar los enteros y sumarlos, y con los decimales sumar .1 + .2 esto va a dar .3 y si da esto redondeo a 1

Comment: Siempre debes mostrar que intentaste, si no parece que esperas que alguien haga el trabajo por vos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es obtener la parte entera del episodio y la parte decimal del episodio y sumarlas cada en acumuladores independientes. Luego la sumatoria de la parte decimal o tercios debes de verificar si es divisible entre 3, pero todo esto se puede hacer con una simple formula.

```
double[] entradas = { 0.2, 0.1, 5.2, 3.1 };

double totalEpisodiosJugados =  0.0;

int episodiosCompletos = 0;
int terciosCompletos = 0;

int episodio = 0;
int tercio = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < entradas.Length; i++)
{
    episodio = (int)Math.Truncate(entradas[i]);
    tercio = (int)(((entradas[i] - episodio) + 0.05) * 10);

    episodiosCompletos += episodio;
    terciosCompletos += tercio;
}

totalEpisodiosJugados = episodiosCompletos + Math.Truncate(terciosCompletos / 3D) + ((terciosCompletos % 3) / 10D);

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Episodios: {0}\nTercios: {1}\nTotal: {2}", episodiosCompletos, terciosCompletos, totalEpisodiosJugados));
Console.ReadKey();
```

El ejemplo que te dejo es sumamente fácil, dentro del bucle lo único que se hace es obtener los valores enteros del episodio y sumarlos. Lo mismo se hace con los tercios con la diferencia que se multiplica entre diez (10) para obtener el valor entero del punto decimal del tercio. Al final se obtiene la sumatoria tanto de los episodios como la de los tercios.

Ahora la parte importante es el cálculo total de los episodios:

**`episodiosCompletos`** `+ Math.Truncate(terciosCompletos / 3D) + ((terciosCompletos % 3) / 10D)`
Episodios anteriormente calculados dentro del bucle.

`episodiosCompletos +` **`Math.Truncate(terciosCompletos / 3D)`** `+ ((terciosCompletos % 3) / 10D)`
Ahora se divide entre 3 la cantidad de tercios y se extrae el valor entero de la misma, con esto obtenemos la cantidad de episodios que hay dentro de los tercios.

`episodiosCompletos + Math.Truncate(terciosCompletos / 3D) +` **`((terciosCompletos % 3) / 10D)`**
Esta parte es importante, ya que, si la sumatorias de los tercios no es un valor divisible entre 3, entonces se obtiene el resto de la división entre 3 para obtener el tercio de episodio sobrante, pero como se devuelve un entero se termina dividiendo entre 10.

---

**Esto mismo se aplica si lo pasas a un excel.**

Resultado:
[image: Resultado de calculo de episodios]

Formulas: Los mismos cálculos que se hacen en C#. Notar que en excel se utiliza la función `RESIDUO` (Su contra parte en inglés es MOD) y en C# el símbolo de porcentaje (`%`) para obtener el resto de la división.
[image: Formulas del calculo de episodios]

```
Entradas    Episodio        Tercio  
0.2         =TRUNCAR(A2)    =(A2-B2)*10 
0.1         =TRUNCAR(A3)    =(A3-B3)*10 
5.2         =TRUNCAR(A4)    =(A4-B4)*10 
3.1         =TRUNCAR(A5)    =(A5-B5)*10 

            =SUMA(B2:B6)    =SUMA(C2:C6)    =B7 + TRUNCAR(C7/3) + (RESIDUO(C7,3) / 10)
            Episodios C.    Tercios C.      Total Episodios Jugados
```

---

**Actualizando:**
Como digo en los comentarios (no programo en php), pero, me surgió la duda del porque te da decimales demás, así que busque en internet como se crea un `array`, como se utiliza un `for` y cual es la contraparte de `Math.Truncate` en php, por lo que me voltee a un **`php fiddle online`** y logre hacer esto. Hasta el momento me a funcionando bien.

```
<?php

$entradas = array(0.2, 0.1, 5.2, 3.1);

$totalEpisodiosJugados =  0.0;

$episodiosCompletos = 0;
$terciosCompletos = 0;

$episodio = 0;
$tercio = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < count($entradas); $i++){ 
    $episodio = intval($entradas[$i]);
    $tercio = ($entradas[$i] - $episodio) * 10;

    $episodiosCompletos += $episodio;
    $terciosCompletos += $tercio;
} 

$totalEpisodiosJugados = $episodiosCompletos + intval($terciosCompletos / 3) + (($terciosCompletos % 3) / 10);


echo "Episodios: ", $episodiosCompletos, ", ";
echo "Tercios: ", $terciosCompletos, ", ";
echo "Total: ", $totalEpisodiosJugados;

?>
```

Comment: @JorgeAlonso, cualquier cosa me avisas.

Comment: Dela Rosa ahora quise convertir el código c# a php y tengo un problema, en c# pongo ciertos valores y me arroja el resultado bien digamos 52.2 pero en php me arroja 52.266666666667, entonces se me ocurrió formatear el texto así: number_format($totalEpisodiosJugados, 1, '.', ''); pero con esto me da 52.3, como podria solucionar esto?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu comentario, te refieres a que ahora nesecitas el codigo en php?. Si es asi te la debo ya que no programo en php. :-)

Comment: Lamentablemente si necesito el codigo en php, pero cuando algo se me complica siempre lo hago primero en c# para tener la idea y luego lo paso a php

Comment: De 52.26667 a 52.3, es como si estuviera redondeando a un decimal con 0.05

Comment: @JorgeAlonso si intentas con `number_format($totalEpisodiosJugados - 0.05, 1, '.', '');`

Comment: La verdad como los valores siempre son con un decimal, no deveria de darte numeros con mas decimales, revisa como estas declarando los tipos de datos en php

Comment: @JorgeAlonso e actualizado mi respuesta y e colocado algo de php, Hasta el momento me ha funcionado, espero pueda servirte de guía, ya que mi fuerte no es php.

Comment: si funciona pero en ciertos números no da lo esperado, por ejemplo si la suma de los episodiosCompletos es 52 y de terciosCompletos es 8 el totalEpisodiosJugados debería ser 54.2 y esta dando 54.1, otro ejemplo episodiosCompletos = 57 y terciosCompletos = 9 el resultado de totalEpisodiosJugados debería ser 60 y da 59.2

Comment: He probado esos valores y tanto en c# como en php dan los valores correctos, como es el tipo de entradas que estas introduciendo.

Comment: @JorgeAlonso basados en los ejemplo de datos que me proporcionaste se llego a que habia que sumar un `0.05` en los calculos de los tercios, Respuesta editada.

Answer (score 2):

No lo puedes hacer con una sola formula, puedes hacer algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna B usa la funcion INT para sacar la parte entera del numero.  La columna C usa esta formula: `=(A1-TRUNC(A1))*3.33`.  Luego en los totales solo redondeas el resultado de la columna C y lo sumas a la columna B.

Comment: No funciona, me marca esto: #¿NOMBRE?

Comment: Si usas excel en español INT seria ENTERO, TRUNC igual a TRUNCAR y para redondear REDONDEAR

Comment: No había tomado eso en cuenta, pero porque multiplicar por 3.33?

Comment: Es el numero magico que necesitas para lograr el resultado que quieres.